# Why is "que" used at the beginning of this sentence and what does the sentence mean as a result?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, pronombres

Why is "que" used at the beginning of the sentence below and what does the sentence mean as a result?

> Que la tecnología no haya sido la adecuada, que los profesores no hayan sido los adecuados, y, sobre todo, que se haya creído que introducir los ordenadores -sin cambiar nada más- servía para algo

Here is the entire paragraph for context:

> La gestión del cerebro está cambiando. Desde el punto de vista
> evolutivo, no nos hemos enfrentado a un problema tan complejo,
> posiblemente, desde la invención de la escritura. Les aconsejo que
> desconfíen de los tecnófilos y de los tecnófobos llenos de certezas
> sobre este asunto. En España, los informes de la Confederación
> Española de Centros de Enseñanza, o del Instituto de Técnicas
> Educativas manifiestan una falta de correlación entre el nivel TIC de
> un centro y los resultados académicos. «No hay ningún estudio serio
> que demuestre que la tecnología ayuda al aprendizaje» es la
> sorprendente conclusión. Esto puede tener varias causas. ***Que la
> tecnología no haya sido la adecuada, que los profesores no hayan sido
> los adecuados, y, sobre todo, que se haya creído que introducir los
> ordenadores -sin cambiar nada más- servía para algo***.

(Taken from an
edited version of [this article](https://www.joseantoniomarina.net/articulos-en-prensa/la-tecnologia-en-el-aprendizaje/) by José Antonio Marina)

Comment: You have to take the previous sentence and *use a colon* in English. **This can have several causes: that the technology and teachers were not suitable [or adequate], and above all that introducing computers - without changing anything else- was believed to be good for something**. servir para algo: to be good for something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding some space will help understanding the role of the word. The role of **que** is a conjunction. Each **que** introduces an entry from a list of unrelated statements among them but related to the introductory statement.

```
Esto puede tener varias causas: 
 - Que la tecnología no haya sido la adecuada, 
 - que los profesores no hayan sido los adecuados, y, sobre todo, 
 - que se haya creído que introducir los ordenadores -sin cambiar nada más- servía para algo.
```

Another example:

```
No entiendo lo que quieres, que te molesta esto, que te molesta esto otro.
```

You can also invert the order but the roles of **que** are the same.

```
Que no funcionó tu depertador, que no encendió tu carro, 
que te detuvo un policia, pero nunca llegas temprano.
```

Comment: Your second example is a different pattern altogether.